# C++ - Is there a difference between declaring a function's return value as void/void* when used in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, pointers, void

Is there a difference between declaring a function's return value as void/void* in case it's used with `std::thread`?

```
void encrypt(/*arguments*/)
{
}

// ...

std::thread(encrypt, /*arguments*/);
```

I read something about using `void*` when working with threads so I wanted to make sure I'm using `void` and not `void*` for a good reason.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess this question was a mistake. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suggest downvoters read the question and not just the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. For instance this function:

```
void func() {  }
```

Is well formed. On the other hand, this one:

```
void* func() {  }
```

Violates a language constraint, and is ill-formed. The difference? You can't omit the return statement, or your program will have undefined behavior.

`void` in this case specifies a lack of a return type, but `void*` is a complete type, and therefore you must specify a value for the function to return.

In the context of `std::thread`, you should specify it as `void`. Any return value is ignored anyway, so just keep your program well formed without returning something meaningless just for the sake of it.

If you read about Pthreads online, by any chance, then they *do* expect a callback that both accepts and returns `void*`. That is so they could support *any parameter* and *any return type*. But that's a C API, so it has to do it like this. The idiomatic C++ API in `std` is type aware. So `void` it is. And if you do care about return values, have a look at `std::future`.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea this question will trigger so many people.

Comment: @TypicalHog - It's not bad at all actually. I assume you are familiar with `pthreads`, where the CB is supposed to return `void*`?

Comment: I'm not, I just read something about using void* with threads on the internet and wanted to make sure I'm using void and not void* for a reason. I'm generally stressing about everything I write way too much.

Comment: @TypicalHog - Oh, well. Pthreads accept and return `void*` to support *any parameter* and *any return type*. But that's a C API, so it has to. The idiomatic C++ API in `std` is more type aware. So `void` it is. And if you do care about return values, have a look at `std::future`.